# In the django templating language how to count the number of items of same type

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am trying to build a table that lists items that can be categorized by type.  I can list out all the items and their types which are returned from my database in a table with no problems.  That is in fact what I would like to do.  Since these items can be categorized by type I see no reason to list the same type multiple times.  The table is listed in order by category type so all items of the same type are already grouped together.  In effect what I have is something along the lines of:

/________________/
/|item A | category A|/
/|item B | category A|/
/|item C | category A|/
/|item D | category B|/
/|item E | category B|/
/|item F | category B|/
/------------------------/
what I actually would like see is

/________________/
/|item A |```````````````|/
/|item B | category A|/
/|item C |_________|/
/|item D |``````````````|/
/|item E | category B|/
/|item F |_________|/
/-------------------------/

This can be done easily enough with a rowspan in the html.  My issue the amount of rows to 'rowspan' is not known ahead.  What I have in the Django template is:

```
                <table class="table table-sm">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td scope="col">Col 1</td>
                            <td scope="col">Col 2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for option in options %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ option.itemNumber }}</td>
                                {% ifchanged option.itemType %}
                                    <td rowspan="how to get this number">{{ option.itemType }}</td>
                                {% endifchanged %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

The only way I can come up with a way to get the count is to create a second, identical, loop, run over the items, count them, then insert that number in rowspan, then continue on with the original loop.  This does not seem to be great solution so I would prefer not to go that route.  Any help here is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by creating a custom filter that returns the count of items in a category.  In the custom filter I ran a database query filtering the result by the category then running a count.

I ended up with:

```
<table class="table table-sm">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <td scope="col">Col 1</td>
          <td scope="col">Col 2</td>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   {% for option in options %}
       <tr>
          <td>{{ option.itemNumber }}</td>
          {% ifchanged option.itemType %}
             <td rowspan="option.itemType|count_types">{{ option.itemType }}</td>
          {% endifchanged %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```